# Can't post to php with HTTP request, but no errors in code

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession

Trying to post text inputs to a PHP script in HTML page. No errors in iOS, and the PHP can successfully post to SQL database. For some reason iOS can't pass the values to the php script successfully.

```
@IBOutlet weak var header: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //helps the return button work
    self.txt1.delegate = self
    self.txt2.delegate = self
    self.txt3.delegate = self
    self.txt4.delegate = self
    self.txt5.delegate = self
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//Text Boxes
@IBOutlet weak var txt1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var txt2: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var txt3: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var txt4: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var txt5: UITextField!

//function to make return button work..
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    txt1.resignFirstResponder()
    txt2.resignFirstResponder()
    txt3.resignFirstResponder()
    txt4.resignFirstResponder()
    txt5.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}

//button action

@IBAction func Submit(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let requestURL = URL(string: "*****")

    //You should use `URLRequest` in Swift 3, mutability is represented by `var`
    var request = URLRequest(url:requestURL!)

    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    //UITextField.text can be nil, you should treat nil cases
    //(Generally avoid using forced unwrapping `!` as far as you can.)
    let song = txt1.text ?? ""
    let artist = txt2.text ?? ""
    let album = txt3.text ?? ""
    let year = txt4.text ?? ""
    let genre = txt5.text ?? ""

    //`song`,... are all Strings, you have no need to add `as String`
    let songPost = "song=" + song
    let artistPost = "&artist=" + artist
    let albumPost = "&album=" + album
    let yearPost = "&year=" + year
    let genrePost = "&genre=" + genre

    //You need to make a single data containing all params
    //(Creating a concatenated String and getting `data` later would be another way.)
    var data = Data()
    data.append(songPost.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    data.append(artistPost.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    data.append(albumPost.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    data.append(yearPost.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    data.append(genrePost.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    request.httpBody = data
    let task =  URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
            print("error=\(error)")
            print(response)

            return
        }

        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(response)")
        }
        //print response
        let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        print("responseString = \(responseString)")
    }
    task.resume()
```

The console spits out a very large message but it says status code should be 200, but is 412.

Am I missing a piece of code that would hit the submit button that is on the HTML page?

Here is the PHP Script:

```
    <html>

   <head>
    <title>Information Gathered</title>
</head>

<body>

    <?php 

    echo "<p>Data Processed!</p>";

    $song = $_POST['song'];
    $artist = $_POST['artist'];
    $album = $_POST['album'];       
    $year = $_POST['year'];
    $genre = $_POST['genre'];

    echo $song . "</br>";
    echo $artist . "</br>";
    echo $album . "</br>";
    echo $year . "</br>";
    echo $genre . "</br>";

    DEFINE ('DB_USER', '****');
    DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', '****');
    DEFINE ('DB_HOST', '****');
    DEFINE ('DB_NAME', '****');

    $dbc = @mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
    OR die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' .
    mysqli_connect_error());

    $sql = "insert into music (song, artist, album, year genre)
            values('$song', '$artist', '$album', '$year', '$genre',)";
    $dbc->query($sql)
    echo "<p> Data Entered!!!</p>"

    ?>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure you have allowed http request on info.plist . Otherwise you can only call secured API ie. https.

For http calling set this on your info.plist

[image: add this row and item]

*412 Status Code Explained*

A 412 status code indicates that one of the conditions the request was made under has failed. A precondition specified in one or more Request-Header fields returned false.

*Why it occurs*

The server does not meet one of the preconditions that the requester put on the request. i.e.,The header of the request specified information about acceptable files that is not applicable to the requested file.

Comment: what exactly does that mean? I added the php to see if there is a miscommunication between the two, is the sql database rejecting the app, or is the app rejecting the php script?